# Trigonometric formulas squared

Tags: trigonometry

Is $\sin^22x=(2\sin x\cos x)^2=4\sin^2x\cos^2x$

and

$\cos^23x=16\cos^6x-24\cos^3x\cos x+9\cos^2x$

I'd like to know $sin^22x=?$ as $x$ not $2x$
same for $\cos^23x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. $\sin ^2(x)$ is an abbreviated way of denoting $(\sin(x))^2$.  And so

$$\sin^2(2x) = (\sin(2x))^2. $$

Then, since $\sin (2x) = 2\sin x \cos x,$ it follows that $$\sin^2(2x) = (\sin(2x))^2 = (2\sin x\cos x)^2=4\sin^2x\cos^2x$$

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the expressions,

$$f(x)=g(x)\implies f^2(x)=g^2(x).$$

The converse is not true because there can be a change of sign.